# How to call a function in directives from index.html page in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, rest, angularjs-directive

I am newbie to Angular.js so i am facing a problem while calling the function in directives from index.html.

When the user enter his phone number i have to call function in Directives.js which is to validate is the number is already exist or not. But i am not getting how to call the function.

my html page

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : userForm.contactno.$invalid  && (userForm.contactno.$dirty || submitted) }">
                <label>ContactNo</label>
                <input type="text" name="contactno" class="form-control" ng-model="user.phone" placeholder="Your Contact No" ng-pattern="/^[789]\d{9}$/" maxlength="10">
                <p ng-show="userForm.contactno.$error.pattern  && (userForm.contactno.$dirty || submitted)" class="help-block">Enter a valid contactno.</p>
            </div>
```

my Directive.js file:

```
 myAppDirectives.
 directive('phone', function() {
  return {
      restrice: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
          console.log("test1");
          angular.element(element).bind('blur', function() {
          var phnNum = this.value;
      $.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost:8989/users/'+phnNum,
          dataType: 'application/json',
          type: 'GET',

success: function( data, status, headers, cfg ){
   console.log("test2");
        console.log("data" +data);
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
       },
error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
       console.log("on success");
       var result=jqXHR;
       //console.log("check" +result.responseText);
       console.log(jqXHR);
       console.log(result.responseText.length);

      if(result.responseText.length===0){
        console.log("you can register now");
       }
     else{
        console.log("User with this number is already registered");
      }
   }            
});           
});              
}            
}    

});
```

Can anyone please help me how to call phone() function in directives from my html page. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `phone` directive to your `<input>` element

```
<input phone type="text" name="contactno" class="form-control" ng-model="user.phone" placeholder="Your Contact No" ng-pattern="/^[789]\d{9}$/" maxlength="10">
```

Comment: You are welcome. You probably want to mark this as the answer then :). Have fun using AngularJS.

Comment: if the number is already registered, How we can show error to the user.   Sorry for asking too-many questions  .

Comment: You want to create an `errorMessage` model on your scope in your controller. Add `transclude:true` in your directive config. On blur, set this errorMessage to `''` an empty string. If error occurs, set it to the error message. I strongly recommned you use the $http service for this. This will prevent you from using scope.apply() when you want to update the errorMessage model outside the angular realm. Please have a look at [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/7u4cIbh34rZAJet9XoGW?p=preview) to get the idea

Answer (score 1):

You can put your directive phone  as a attribute in input box:-)

```
<input phone type="text" name="contactno" class="form-control" ng-model="user.phone" placeholder="Your Contact No" ng-pattern="/^[789]\d{9}$/" maxlength="10">
```

But here is the thing don't use $.ajax it is not a angular function if you want asyn calls use $http that is native service in angular js.

```
$http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

[Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Thank you for your replay and suggestion

Comment: keep in mind if you are using try to utilize it to the full happy programming